# Serve static content from a base URL in Dropwizard 0.7.1

Tags: dropwizard

This was easy using Dropwizard 0.6.2, but with the move to 0.7.x it has become significantly more difficult. I can get it to work, but not in a manner entirely suitable. I'd like for my RESTful API to be available at a "/api/*" point, and the static content to be available from the root URL "/".

The best I can currently achieve with 0.7.1 is to serve the API content from "/api/*", and the static content from "/api/assets/*". This isn't awful, but it would make things much nicer if I could achieve the originally stated goal. I have tried various permutations of configuring my AssetBundle(), have tried using https://github.com/bazaarvoice/dropwizard-configurable-assets-bundle, have tried taking what I saw in the source and creating my own dedicated StaticAssetsBundle class, all to no avail.

What I have working right now (which manages to serve my static content from "/api/assets/*") is as follows:

`public void initialize(Bootstrap<ConfigConfiguration> bootstrap) {
    bootstrap.addBundle(new AssetsBundle());
}`

.. and in my configuration file I have ...

`server:
    type: simple
    connector:
        type: http
        port: 8458
    applicationContextPath: /api
    .....`

Can anyone give me a concise and **complete** example of how to achieve the serving of my static content from "/" while still retaining the serving of my API at "/api/*"? I've searched far and wide and have found hints, partial answers, answers that don't seem to work in 0.7.1, and am about ready to give up and just serve my static content from a completely separate server instance (which is probably what the DW folks think I should do anyway).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about something like this in your `Application`:

```java
@Override
public void initialize(Bootstrap<ExampleConfiguration> bootstrap) {
  // Static assets are in src/main/resources/assets
  bootstrap.addBundle(new AssetsBundle("/assets", "/"));
}

@Override
public void run(ExampleConfiguration configuration, Environment environment) throws Exception {
  environment.jersey().setUrlPattern("/api/*");
}
```

Comment: I thought I had tried that before, with no success, but to be certain I re-ran that arrangement. At first I thought it still wasn't working, but realized that I had not modified my configuration file to match. I changed the config to read **applicationContextPath: /** with the changes you suggest above, and ... it worked. I can now server my API from "/api/*" and my static documents from "/". Forcing me to re-visit this approach caused me to exercise all the permutations needed to find the answer. Thanks!